# How to filter out lines having 2 similar values?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want filter out lines having ***same number*** -> ***same number***

from this text

```
    [325194/777232]/var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin:  100%  extents: 5 -> 1   [ OK ]
    [325195/777232]/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin: 100%  extents: 4 -> 1   [ OK ]
    [325255/777232]/var/cache/man/de/index.db:  100%  extents: 2 -> 2   [ OK ]
    [325521/777232]/var/log/syslog: 100%  extents: 7 -> 1   [ OK ]
    [325525/777232]/var/log/lastlog:    100%  extents: 2 -> 2   [ OK ]
    [325531/777232]/var/log/syslog.1:   100%  extents: 5 -> 1   [ OK ]
    [325572/777232]/var/log/kern.log:   100%  extents: 6 -> 1   [ OK ]
    [325589/777232]/var/log/auth.log:   100%  extents: 3 -> 1   [ OK ]
    [325621/777232]/var/log/faillog:    100%  extents: 2 -> 2   [ OK ]
    [325625/777232]/var/log/wtmp:   100%  extents: 3 -> 1   [ OK ]
    [325627/777232]/var/log/kern.log.1: 100%  extents: 2 -> 1   [ OK ]
    [325644/777232]/var/log/cups/access_log.1:  100%  extents: 2 -> 1   [ OK ]
    [325810/777232]/var/log/auth.log.1: 100%  extents: 2 -> 1   [ OK ]
```

Comment: By "filter out", do you mean "show only these" or "remove these"?

Comment: I mean "remove these".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the lines that *has* the *same_number -> same_number* pattern:

```bsh
grep -E '([[:digit:]]+)[[:blank:]]+->[[:blank:]]+\1[[:blank:]]'
```

- `-E` enables ERE (Extended Regular Expression)
- `([[:digit:]]+)` matches one or more digits and put in captured group 1
- `[[:blank:]]+` matches one or more horizontal whitespaces
- `->` matches literally
- `\1` refers to the first captured group
- `[[:blank:]]` matches a whitespace after that

*You can use the similar logic with other popular text-processing tools/languages like `sed`, `awk`, `perl`.*

To get the lines that *do not have* the pattern, only add the `-v` option:

```bsh
grep -vE '([[:digit:]]+)[[:blank:]]+->[[:blank:]]+\1[[:blank:]]'
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
[325194/777232]/var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin:  100%  extents: 5 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325195/777232]/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin: 100%  extents: 4 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325255/777232]/var/cache/man/de/index.db:  100%  extents: 2 -> 2   [ OK ]
[325521/777232]/var/log/syslog: 100%  extents: 7 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325525/777232]/var/log/lastlog:    100%  extents: 2 -> 2   [ OK ]
[325531/777232]/var/log/syslog.1:   100%  extents: 5 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325572/777232]/var/log/kern.log:   100%  extents: 6 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325589/777232]/var/log/auth.log:   100%  extents: 3 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325621/777232]/var/log/faillog:    100%  extents: 2 -> 2   [ OK ]
[325625/777232]/var/log/wtmp:   100%  extents: 3 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325627/777232]/var/log/kern.log.1: 100%  extents: 2 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325644/777232]/var/log/cups/access_log.1:  100%  extents: 2 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325810/777232]/var/log/auth.log.1: 100%  extents: 2 -> 1   [ OK ]

% grep -E '([[:digit:]]+)[[:blank:]]+->[[:blank:]]+\1[[:blank:]]' file.txt
[325255/777232]/var/cache/man/de/index.db:  100%  extents: 2 -> 2   [ OK ]
[325525/777232]/var/log/lastlog:    100%  extents: 2 -> 2   [ OK ]
[325621/777232]/var/log/faillog:    100%  extents: 2 -> 2   [ OK ]

% grep -vE '([[:digit:]]+)[[:blank:]]+->[[:blank:]]+\1[[:blank:]]' file.txt
[325194/777232]/var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin:  100%  extents: 5 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325195/777232]/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin: 100%  extents: 4 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325521/777232]/var/log/syslog: 100%  extents: 7 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325531/777232]/var/log/syslog.1:   100%  extents: 5 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325572/777232]/var/log/kern.log:   100%  extents: 6 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325589/777232]/var/log/auth.log:   100%  extents: 3 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325625/777232]/var/log/wtmp:   100%  extents: 3 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325627/777232]/var/log/kern.log.1: 100%  extents: 2 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325644/777232]/var/log/cups/access_log.1:  100%  extents: 2 -> 1   [ OK ]
[325810/777232]/var/log/auth.log.1: 100%  extents: 2 -> 1   [ OK ]
```

Comment: Can one also use `\s+` for the spaces or is it different?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto `\s` inplace of `[[:blank:]]` would work too.

Comment: There's a bug: the regex also matches lines where the first number is a prefix of the second (e.g. `4 -> 42`). Adding a word boundary (or `[[:blank:]]`) at the end of the regex would fix this.

Comment: @nomadictype Good catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with GNU Awk (`gawk`).

Assuming the input is stored in `MY_FILE` and you want to see only lines with the **same numbers**, it might look like this:

```bsh
gawk '{match($0,/([[:digit:]]+)\s*->\s*([[:digit:]])+/,M);if(M[1]==M[2])print$0}' MY_FILE
```

If you want to remove lines with equal numbers and show only those with **different numbers**, simply replace the `==` with `!=`:

```bsh
gawk '{match($0,/([[:digit:]]+)\s*->\s*([[:digit:]])+/,M);if(M[1]!=M[2])print$0}' MY_FILE
```

---

Explanation:

`gawk` will run the instructions inside the curly braces for each line, which are:

```bsh
match($0, /([[:digit:]]+)\s*->\s*([[:digit:]])+/, M) ; 
if(M[1] == M[2]) print$0
```

This means, match the regular expression `([[:digit:]]+)\s*->\s*([[:digit:]])+` against the whole line (`$0`) and store the match object/array in variable `M`.

Then compare the contents of match group 1 and 2 (the number before and after the arrow respectively) and print the whole line if those are equal (if you use `==`) or different (if you use `!=`).

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need regular expression matching if your data are structured as delimited fields.

In your case, the `->` always appears as the 5th whitespace-delimited field, so it's enough to test the values of the 4th and 6th:

```
awk '$6 != $4' file
```

If the position of the `->` varies, then you could do something like

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i == "->" && $(i-1) != $(i+1)) {print; break}}' file
```

or split the line on `->` first and then split the parts either side on whitespace and test the last field of the first part against the first field of the second:

```
awk -F' -> ' '{
  n=split($1,a,/[ \t]+/); split($2,b,/[ \t]+/); if(b[1] != a[n]) print
}' file
```

Comment: Some filenames will include spaces so position of -> indeed varies. If awk was able to begin from end of line it could be solution for case.